# Cannot compile CastCompanionLibrary in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, chromecast

I want to use CastComponaionLibrary but I'm using Eclipse and not Android Studio.
So I created a new project and copied all CastCompanionLibrary sources into it.
I also added references to:

- android-support-v7-appcompat
- android-support-v7-mediarouter
- google-play-services_lib

In this new project I get these compilation errors:

- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider. Fix the build path then try building this project
- The type android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files VideoCastControllerActivity.java

any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: It's easy. Update your project's android private libraries with **android-support-v4.jar**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. this jar is already included under Android Private Libraries. Anything else?

Comment: Hmmm... having `android-support-v4.jar` in `libs/` should be sufficient, as that is where that particular class lives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to include v4 library since that is part of the v7 libraries, so remove that. Then follow the instructions in this G+ community [post](https://plus.google.com/117916055521642810655/posts/NxcYH6yPeUj)

Comment: Ali, thank you for your answer. I did a fresh checkout from git and was able to import the project properly, without having to add additional references. However, I get the following compilation errors now: 
Cannot invoke setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>(){}) on the primitive type void VideoCastManager.java /CastCompanionLibrary-android/src/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast line 1106

Comment: Did you update your Google Play services library (using SDK manager)?

Comment: I had google play services version 15 and updated to 16 and everything is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I solved this problem:

- In android.support.vX -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add
- Choose the related project/s to the android.support.vX
- Press OK
- Do the same and remove the project/s added