# Eclipse - The project was not built since its build path is incomplete

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

I am trying to import a project into Eclipse and I'm getting the errors:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
> find the class file for
> android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider. Fix the
> build path then try building this project
>
> The type android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider
> cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
> files TrucklistActivity.java

I Added the External Jars from the sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat folder:

[image]

Yes I am aware that using Android Studio would be better than Eclipse but I just want to get this projected imported into Eclipse.

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but if you have the Gradle plugin for Eclipse, can you import the existing project as File/Import/Gradle Project, and then it will setup your classpaths for you based on the dependencies in your Gradle config from Android Studio?

Comment: I seriously doubt your error could be as simple as this but...

Possibly duplicate post of [Build path incomplete only in some workspaces android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454666/build-path-incomplete-only-in-some-workspaces-android) e.g. you're missing the JVM above?

Comment: @JGlass I added the JRE system library but those errors are still there

Comment: Dang, what about this [cannot-compile castcompanionlibrary in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686667/cannot-compile-castcompanionlibrary-in-eclipse), somewhat related?

Comment: Move Android dependencies higher in the 'Order and Export' tab.